# How to explicitly cast argument to match an expected function parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, type-traits

I am trying to write a generic function to compute an average over a certain range.

```
template <typename Range, typename Ret, typename Func>
Ret average(Range range, Ret zero, Func extract) {
  Ret sum = zero;
  int numElements = 0;
  for (const auto& elem : range) {
    sum += extract(elem);
    ++numElements;
  }
  if (numElements > 0)
    sum /= numElements;
  return sum;
}
```

The problam I am having is with the usage of the `/=` operator, but to better clarify the arguments of this function, let me clarify them:

- `Range range` is any object that defines a range through `begin()` and `end()` member funcitons. I may need to add `const&` to avoid unnecessary copying.
- `Ret zero` defines the neutral element of the addition used when computing the average. It could be just a scalar, but will work with vectors or matrices too for example.
- `Func extract` is a function (usually given as a lambda function) that converts the elements of the range into `Ret` values that I average over. In practice I use it as a getter of a specific field in big objects that I iterate over.

  I could probably define it as `std::function<Ret(decltype(*range.begin()))>` or something similar, if C++ didn't have problems deducting types this way.

I assume that `Ret` provides *some* `/=` operator that the above function can work with, but I do not want to require it to take an `int` specifically.

In my use case, for example, `Ret` works with `float`-s and this gives me an annoying warning:

`warning: 'argument': conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data`

So, **what are my options to make the above function clean and work with any suitable `operator/=`?**

---

I tried, for example, to deduct the type of the right argument of the operator and explicitly cast to it:

```
template <typename Range, typename Ret, typename Func>
Ret average(Range range, Ret zero, Func extract) {
  Ret sum = zero;
  int numElements = 0;
  for (const auto& elem : range) {
    sum += extract(elem);
    ++numElements;
  }
  using F = std::remove_pointer<decltype(&Ret::operator/=)>;

  if (numElements > 0)
    sum /= static_cast<typename boost::function_traits<F>::arg1_type>(numElements);
  return sum;
}
```

But I get a lot of compile errors, suggesting that I don't know what I am doing. Starts with:

```
error: 'boost::detail::function_traits_helper<std::remove_pointer<SpecificTypeUsedAsRet &(__cdecl SpecificTypeUsedAsRet::* )(float)> *>': base class undefined
```

That's probably because `boost::function_traits` does not work with member functions, just regular ones?

I am also concerned that this solution may not work when:

- The `operator/=` is not given as a member function, but as a regular function with two arguments.
- The `operator/=` is overloaded with respect to its right operand. An `int` may match only one of the overloads - so there is no ambiguity, but `decltype` won't know which overload to take.
- I would prefer not to use `boost` but stick to the powers provided by newest C++ standards

Comment: Having to deduce either the argument type or return type of *Arithmetic* or *Compound* operators is almost always a sign of bad API or some misuse; operator overloading and its uses are to make simple things simple and clear. Doing some deductions at its *point-of-use* is doesn't smell good; That said, you can delegate the line `sum /= ...` to a utility `class-template` that treats certain categories of types separately; You can templatize on `float` to treat the warning if you aren't concerned about precision loss;

Comment: Is the above `average` function a design flaw or a misuse? Because I doubt that a `Float` class (used as `Ret`) encapsulating a built-in `float` would have a division operator with an integer. I don't see how to make the delegated utility class robust enough to work with any `Ret`.

Comment: "I assume that Ret provides some /= operator that the above function can work with, but I do not want to require it to take an int specifically." - but you can accept to test a limited list of potential types for divisor? I mean: is good for you if the divisor is `int`, or `long`, or..., or `float` or `double`, or `long double` or nothing else?

Comment: It could be anything. Maybe a `BigNum` class? Or a rational type? I do not expect the number of elements to exceed `int` ever, but the operators provided by `Ret` may operate on any type that `int` is convertible to.

Comment: It would improve the question to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing an example of the undesirable case

Answer (score 0):

You could simply declare `Ret numElements = 0;` instead of making it an `int`. If it has `/=` operator, it probably has an `++` operator; or you could use `num_elements += 1` instead.